# Using C# Restsharp, how can I replicate a form post?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, restsharp

I am using a rest service to get back some json data.  As a test harness, they gave me a url and  if I go to the url in the browser, I have a form and i can put some json in a textarea and then submit the form and i get the json result back on the page reload.

I am now trying to replicate this programatically by using RestSharp in C# but i am running into an issue where the results from the call is the html of the page that i am going to (instead of the json result)

Here is my code:

```
var client = new RestClient {BaseUrl = new Uri("http://myhost.com:22333") };        

var request = new RestRequest { Method = Method.POST, Resource = "/site/api", RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

 request.AddBody(new
        {
            fieldtype = "name", value = "joe"
        });
        request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");

        client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var jsonDto = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<ResultObj>(response);
```

if i look at response.Content in the debugger (before any deserialization) i see an html string of the web page that i went to with the form to post (something like this)

```
<html>
<body>
<form method='POST'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Enter the JSON:</td>
<td>
<textarea name="json_input" cols="80" rows="30">
</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='Submit' value='submit'></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone advise what i am missing here as I am expecting to get the same json result back in response.Content that i see after submitting the form in the browser

Comment: What's the `url` when you post the `form` with data in test harness?

Comment: If you can share the url and a sample json, we will be able to help.

Comment: Please make sure that API method is POST(not GET or something else)

Comment: Please check that there is not an additional path needed beyond /api. E.g. site/api/customers

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao - http://myhost.com:22333/site/Api

Comment: I'm sure it has nothing to do but...have you tried to add a content-length header to your request?

Comment: Try using Chrome dev tools network tab to see if anything is sent to a different URL when you click submit.

Comment: can you use ajax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `form` has a text field named `json_input` that will be used as the request parameter.

```
<textarea name="json_input" cols="80" rows="30">
```

And your `AddBody` method indicated you are sending the request with `fieldtype` and `value` parameters.

Try replacing the `AddBody` method with the following:

```
request.AddBody(new { json_input = "{ fieldtype : \"name\", value : \"joe\"}" });

//OR

request.AddParameter("json_input",
                    "{ fieldtype : \"name\", value : \"joe\"}");
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the *HTML* code, the action URL of the form will be waiting for the following form fields:

- json_input

And in your code you are calling `request.AddBody(new { ... })` that does the following:

- As you set the `RequestFormat` to `DataFormat.Json`, the serializer to be used by default is `JsonSerializer`.
- *Content-Type* header is setup to "application/json".
- `new { ... }` will be serialized into a json string and `AddBody()` call is transformed into a call to `AddParameter()` using as parameter *name* "application/json", as parameter *value* the json string, and as parameter *type* `ParameterType.RequestBody`.

Using **Fiddler2** you can see the *POST* made by your code:

[image: code fiddler]

As it is shown in the image, the request body is `{"fieldtype":"name", "value":"joe"}`, this may works if server is expecting the form fields *fieldtype* and *value*; but is expecting a request body like this `json_input={ "fieldtype": "name", "value": "joe" }` (decoded for clarity). In the next image, you can see the *POST* using the *HTML*:

[image: html fiddler]

Also, the type of the added parameter is `ParameterType.RequestBody`, so only the first body added using `AddBody()` function is used, the rest is discarded.

You can solve this problem by creating a `Parameter` called "json_input" and passing it to the function `AddParameter()`:

```
var client = new RestClient { BaseUrl = new Uri("http://myhost.com:22333") };

var request = new RestRequest { Resource = "/site/api", RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

var param = new Parameter
{
    Type = ParameterType.GetOrPost,
    Name = "json_input",
    Value = new
    {
        fieldtype = "name",
        value = "joe"
    }
};

request.AddParameter(param);

client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();

var response = client.Post(request);            

if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
{
    var deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
    var jsonDto = deserializer.Deserialize<ResultObj>(response);
}
```

Using `ParameterType.GetOrPost` allows you to add  as many parameters (form fields) as you want.

As you can see in my code, I added an `if` statement checking for *HTTP* `StatusCode` returned in the response because usually *HTTP POST* returns a **201 Created** code.

You can add an `else` statement to check for the properties `response.ErrorException` and `response.ErrorMessage` to see what the problem is.

Perhaps, as the *POST* is not well formed, the server redirects you to the same page to try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to create a model based on what the API controller method expects.
I have created an example using the info you provided, you will need to add all of the form fields to the model.

```
//Model for the data you are sending
public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//define client, request and model
var client = new RestClient {BaseUrl = new Uri("http://myhost.com:22333") };        
var request = new RestRequest { Method = Method.POST, Resource = "/site/api", RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
var testModel = new TestModel() { Name = "joe" };

//serialize model as json and add it to the request
var json = request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(testModel);
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

//execute request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Make sure you are posting to the  correct URI for the API.

Continue to inspect the HTML you receive and see if its giving you any errors.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var client = new RestClient {"http://myhost.com:22333/site/api"};        

var request = new RestRequest {  RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

 request.AddBody(new
        {
            fieldtype = "name", value = "joe"
        });

        client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
        var response = client.Post(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var jsonDto = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<ResultObj>(response);
```

Comment: this seems to do the same thing as my current code in the question